# How to show image in django admin

Tags: python, django

This question was already asked ,but that was not solving my problem.i have searched a lot but i am unable to show the images as thumbnail in admin panel.

**MY models.py is**

```
thumb_impression=models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
cust_pic=models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True ,)

def admin_thumbnail(self):
    return mark_safe(u'<img src="%s" />' % (self.cust_pic))

admin_thumbnail.short_description = 'Thumbnail'
# admin_thumbnail.allow_tags = True

admin_thumbnail = property(admin_thumbnail)
```

**Admin.py is**

class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
readonly_fields =  ('balance','terms_and_condition')

fieldsets =  [
    ('Account Details',{
        'fields':['cust_id','cust_first_name','cust_middle_name','cust_last_name','cust_pic']
    }),
    ('Thumbnail',{
        'fields':['cust_pic']
    }),
]

list_display = (
    'cust_first_name',

    'cust_last_name',
    'admin_thumbnail',
)
```

admin.site.register(Account,AccountAdmin)

**urls.py is**

```
urlpatterns=[
url(r'^',include(router.urls)),

url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

]

I tried previous solution but i am unable to find the correct answer.please help me to find out the solution.please give me a proper example so that i can apply it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def admin_thumbnail(self):
    return u'<img src="%s" />' % (self.image.url)
admin_thumbnail.short_description = 'Thumbnail'
admin_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
```

The list_display bit looks identical too, and I know that works. The only thing that looks suspect to me is your indentation - the two lines beginning  image_img at the end of your models.py code should be level with def image_img(self):, like this:

```
def image_img(self):
    if self.image:
        return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.image.url_125x125
    else:
        return '(Sin imagen)'
image_img.short_description = 'Thumb'
image_img.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper definition as explained by the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('bar',)

    def bar(self, obj):  # receives the instance as an argument
        return '<img src="{thumb}" />'.format(
            thumb=obj.image.url,
        )
    bar.allow_tags = True
    bar.short_description = 'sometext'


admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Obviously don't add the property to readonly_fields

Comment: It doesn't matter if that function will be in model or in admin. It can be even property in model, but it is tricky to set `allow_tags` and `short_description` on property.

Comment: i am unable to show images.please take a look on my code

Comment: @CPVerma why have you added the attribute to readonly_fields?

Comment: @Hedde van what should i do.please describe me in detail.this code wasted my 5-7 days.